# How to launch Visual studio as Administrator from citrix access platform

Tags: visual-studio-2010, citrix

I need to launch my VS 2010 in admin mode from citrix access platform. Here I'm not able to access the properties of VS2010 shortcut.

thanks ,
saravanan.

Comment: Ask your administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the icon you're using to start it, and click "Run as administrator".

If that option doesn't appear, maybe it's been disabled by your Citrix administrator?